# Does the Kineticist feat Augmented Elements function as Expanded Element for choosing Infusion and Utility Wild Talents?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, kineticist

Does the Kineticist feat [Augmented Elements](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/path-of-war/feats/augmented-elements-general/) function as [Expanded Element (Su)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/Kineticist/#TOC-Expanded-Element-Su-) for choosing Infusion and Utility Wild Talents?

Augmented Elements simply put is... you get your choice of an additional simple blast of any element at an extra Burn cost of 1 if not acquired the normal way; As well as gaining the Psionic Sub-type for Psionic feats, metapsionic feats, psionic creation feats. And though not mentioned more than likely the ability to hold a psionic focus.

Expanded Element simply put is ... you gain a secondary element. Choosing the same Element grants its composite Blasts as well as your choice of an infusion or utility related to that element. While a new element grants that element's simple blast and basic use (wild talent).

EX: Prime Element: Aether

Augmented Element: chose Air

Can I then choose Utilities, Infusions and Composite Blast of the Air Element.

Answer (score 2):

## No.

[Augmented Elements](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/path-of-war/feats/augmented-elements-general/) states:

> Benefit: **You learn a simple blast from any element** (including your primary element, if there is another blast for you to choose). Unless you later gain access to this blast through another method, you increase its burn cost by 1 whenever you use it. In addition, you gain the psionic subtype, allowing you to take psionic feats, metapsionic feats, and psionic item creation feats. If you do not have your primary element’s basic utility talent (for example, if you have traded it away with an archetype), you also gain that wild talent.

This does not grant you a [kineticist's element](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/kineticist-elements/) for that blast, nor does it say it functions as [expanded elements](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/Kineticist/#TOC-Expanded-Element-Su-), it only grants you an simple blast from any element.